# Как сделать кнопку из изображения python, pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

Как сделать кнопку, которая представляет из себя изображение в pygame? Также нужно её анимировать, то есть, когда ты на неё нажимаешь - она вдавливается.

Answer (score 1):

Все очень просто. Вы рисуете кнопку непосредственно на изображении экрана. Запоминаете координаты того места, где находится кнопка. Если она прямоугольная, то координаты углов, если круглая, то центр окружности и радиус. Если овальная.... то с этим все послоднее. Дальше делаете вот что

```
 for self.i in pygame.event.get(): 
                       self.x1 = self.i.pos[0]
                       self.y1 = self.i.pos[1]
```

вы используете метод захвата координат клика мы и переедаете их переменным x1  и y1. А потом, делаете условие If и проверяете, попал ли пользователь на кнопку. Как-то так.

```
 if self.x > 206 and self.x < 428 and self.y > 388 and self.y < 461: # первая кнопка

                                window1 = YouAreRight()
                            else:
                                window1 = YouAreWrong()
```

Сосбственно говоря в этот момент нажатия кнопки (клика по выделенной области) должен происходить механизм подмена одного рисунка - кнопки на рисунок нажатой кнопки.
Подмена должа осуществляться через использование метода blit. Как-то так

```
button=[pygame.image.load('button (1).png'),pygame.image.load('button (2).png')]
win.blit(button[0], (x, y))
win.blit(button[1], (x, y))
```

Comment: А как же сделать, чтобы кнопка(изображение) вдавливалось? Или уменьшалось в размере, а потом возвращалось в исходный размер

Comment: для этого через  Blit происходит подмена одного рисунка кнопки другим. См. описанную мной выше методику.

Comment: Что-то у вас с отступами сильно не то.